# Specify date format in talend

Tags: talend

I have used `TalendDate.addDate(TalendDate.getCurrentDate(),-1,"DD")` and the out put is "Wed Dec 28 23:51:27 IST 2016" . 
I want it in "2016-12-28" format.

Is there any way to get that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will format it how you want it.

```
TalendDate.formatDate("yyyy-MM-dd",TalendDate.addDate(TalendDate.getCurrentDate(),-1,"DD"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Be sure that in your output component, a date model is defined for this field.

[image: Example below with a tLogRow]